# How do I replace the word "hello" with "goodbye" in every file in this directory, and also recursively?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Suppose I have many files in this directory. I want to replace "hello" with "goodbye" everywhere, also recursively

Comment: Do you care if substrings are also replaced?  All current answers will replace words like "shellout" with "sgoodbyeut".  I would think they should deal with token replacement only.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758963/find-and-replace-with-sed-in-directory-and-sub-directories

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello/goodbye/g' {} +`

Comment: You may want to check that pattern. You may end up with instances of sgoodbyeil!

Answer (score 1):

for file in $(find ./) ; do sed -e 's/hello/goodbye/g' $file > tmp && mv tmp $file ; done

Answer (score 0):

You can use a perl one-liner

```
perl -p -i -e 's/oldstring/newstring/g' `find ./ -name *.html`
```

(Taken from here http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2005/08/18/perl-oneliner-recursive-search-and-replace/)

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the formatting... essential backticks were getting lost.