# Search and replace in a console

Tags: unix, replace, freebsd

I want to search and replace string located in a several files via bash console.

Here is the command I use to find a string in a file:

`grep "string" * -r`

so the above is for searching, now I need a command to replace the `string`.

Is that even possible?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996460/how-do-i-replace-the-word-hello-with-goodbye-in-every-file-in-this-directory/4996483

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

It's cranky and difficult, but it's one way to do it.

Here's an example:

```
sed -i 's/ugly/beautiful/g' /home/bruno/old-friends/sue.txt
```

This replaces ugly with beautiful in sue.txt.

Comment: Fails on OS X (FreeBSD) with `command a expects \ followed by text`.

Comment: you have a typo, it sounds like. There's no command "a" in my example.

Comment: The thing is you need to provide backup extension on Mac/FreeBSD, e.g. `sed -i .bk 's/e/d/g' myfile.txt`